# Solo usar una casilla en cada evento de la librería fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Estoy ingresando eventos a FullCalendar, pero tengo el problema de que cada evento abarca demasiadas horas (o casillas). Necesito que cada evento use una casilla para que se vea más ordenado.

[image: calendario actual]

Este es el JSON de mi evento id:

```
'{{ $hora->id }}', title: 'Paciente: {{ $hora->paciente_nombre." ".$hora->paciente_apellido }} 
Profesional : {{ $hora->profesional_nombre." ".$hora->profesional_apellido }} ', start: moment('{{ $hora->fecha_hora }}').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'), backgroundColor: '{{ $hora->color }}',
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que *cada evento abarca demasiadas horas (o casillas)*? Si tu evento dura 1 hora, es correcto que tome 2 casillas. ¿Qué es lo que realmente estás buscando?

Comment: eso no esta en formato json. puedes editar la pregunta y resumiendo el código a lo mínimo necesario para entender como lo inicializas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es que FullCalendar cuenta con un [`defaultTimedEventDuration`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultTimedEventDuration/) y este es de 2 horas:

> Duración, default: '02:00:00' (2 horas)

Y como no estás especificando el parámetro `end` en el evento entonces se asume el valor de 2 horas como duración total del evento:

> Si no se especifica el *end* en el evento, aparecerá esta duración al renderizar.

Entonces tienes dos opciones:

1. Calcular el parámetro `end` aumentando 30 minutos al valor del parámetro `start` para que ocupe solo una casilla usando alguna función.
2. Cambiar el `defaultTimedEventDuration`:

   ```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
       defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:30:00',
       forceEventDuration: true,
       // ...    
   });
   ```

   Lo que hace el flag [`forceEventDuration`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/forceEventDuration/) es forzar el cálculo del `end`.

Bueno, es lo que se me ocurre por ahora.

### Nota

Considera que las soluciones que estoy planteando van en contra de todo el comportamiento original de FullCalendar el cual es correcto, es decir, es correcto que los eventos tengan una duración si es que no has especificado `allDay: true` y también es correcto que los eventos se traslapen cuando ocurren al mismo tiempo

Comment: creo que el problema de esta solución es que el calendario esta mal configurado, los eventos durarían menos lo que realmente duran. Tal vez una alternativa posible es toquetear con estilos para cambiar la apariencia únicamente.

Comment: @rnrneverdies si estoy de acuerdo en que este hack no es muy adecuado, por la pregunta parece a Luis no le importan mucho la duración de los eventos y con esto lo puede resolver.  Sin embargo, el comportamiento original de FullCalendar es el correcto en mi opinión

Comment: cesar fíjate mi respuesta... me tengo que ir. saludos.

Comment: toda la razón, me faltó el parámetro END :/ !! en realidad lo agregué desde un principio pero con la misma fecha y hora del START y pasaba que tomaba las dos horas por default. gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Como complemento de la respuesta de @Cesar, Si quires que se vea menos cargado, pero sin dejar de establecer la duración real de los eventos (es decir, sin fijar los eventos a 30 min en el caso que dure 1 hr 30 min.), puedes modificar la *apariencia* aprovechando la opción [className](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/#color-options). Esto tiene como ventaja que mueves la cuestión visual afuera de la lógica de tu aplicación. Y te permite que los eventos se ocupen un espacio proporcional a su duración.

Explicación:

- Necesitas definir dos reglas tu CSS para cada color:
- `.color` donde defines el color del borde y pones el fondo a transparente.
- `.color .fc-content` done pones el color de fondo del area con texto y el color del texto en si.
- En cada evento pones el nombre de la clase según el color que corresponda en la opcion `className`.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {

  var fcal = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    events: [{
      title: "Evento",
      start: moment().startOf('day').hour(7),
      end: moment().startOf('day').hour(9),
      className: 'azul'
    },{
      title: "Evento",
      start: moment().startOf('day').hour(8).minute(30),
      end: moment().startOf('day').hour(10),
      className: 'rojo'
    }]

  });

});
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.0/fullcalendar.css";

.rojo {
  border-color: red;
  background: transparent;
}

.azul {
  border-color: blue;
  background: transparent;
}
  
.rojo .fc-content {
  background: red;
}

.azul .fc-content {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Excelente solución!